# passing td data to a hidden input and then posting with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms

I have a form that I have shortended for simplicty but the concept is the same.

```
<form method=post action= somephp.php>
<table>
<tr><td><input name= first></tr>// These input are where people enter 
<tr><td><input name= second></tr>// numbers. They then click on
<tr><td><input name= third></tr>//calculate and the results appear
<tr><td><input name= fourth></tr>//in the below table
<td>Result one <input type = "hidden" name="somename" value=""></td>// 
<td>Result two <input type = "hidden" name="somename1  value=""></td>  
<button>Calculate</button>
<button type submit>save</button>
</form>
```

The form works fine . The maths for the form is performed using javascript. I get the values of the results in the  result one and two as expected .

Now for my problem After I have clicked calculate and got my results I click on the save button and want it to post all of the inputs including the hidden ones to a PHP script.

I am having problems posting the hidden feilds.

It works if I place a figure in the value attribute but what I want and have been struggling all night with is how can I post the result one and two feilds to my PHP script via the hidden feild.

I have been trying in vain to get the variable from my js script to act as the value for the hidden feild but keep getting undefined index error in PHP. I think it may be because the page has already loaded. I have attached the variable that holds the value for result one and result two to onChange event etc but can not get this to work.

As a summary - how can I pass a td inner HTML (result 1 and result 2) to  hidden inputs value for posting to a PHP script. 
I am open to other solutions

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<script>

var a = document.getElementByID('result one id').value;
var b = document.getElementByID('HIDDEN INPUT ID').value;
```

I want a = b

but am struggling

Comment: You really need to use quotes for all your form stuff. Some browsers let that go by; many don't. You mention JS stuff, but haven't shown it. Plus, this won't work `<button type submit>`.

Comment: don't trust your calculation total inside the hidden input, they could just change it from there, i suggest making those calculation total in backend. i'm not saying scrap the calculation on the front, just use it as presentation.

Comment: ^^ perfectly said. JS side calculations can be easily be tampered with.

Comment: I have used quotes , sorry I can add

Comment: The various scripts I have and the real code is around 3000 lines long and is used to calculate protein formulations. Its for personal use origionally as pure javascript as a work tool. I have recently decided that I want to trend these results so am looking for a way to put the data in a databse. I decided I would add an example or snippet (all be it a poorly sytaxed one) of where my problem was. Ideally I do not want to re-write the calculations in PHP.

Comment: So when you click calculate, a javascript function populates the values for the two hidden inputs? But those don't appear in the $_POST array in PHP? There's no reason that shouldn't work. The problem with your question as you've posed it is there's not really any error in the code. The problem may be in the javascript which we can't see.

Comment: You may be right - However I have used this tool for a couple of years the javascript is fine. The avenues I have tried have failed and that may well be due to flaws in my javascript that I have tried for this issue but I simply just want a solution for passing a td html to a hidden input so I am in a position to post it.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using jquery to set values of the hidden fields.

```
<form method=post action= somephp.php>
<table>
    <tr><td><input name= "first" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name= "second" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name= "third" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name= "fourth" /></td></tr>
    <td>Result one <input id="hidden1"  type = "text" name="somename" value=""/></td> 
    <td>Result two <input id="hidden2" type = "text" name="somename1"  value=""/></td>
<button id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<button id="submit" type="submit">save</button>
    </table>
</form>
```

And the jquery

```
    $(document).on('click', '#calculate', function(){ //you could perform your calculations here or define a separate function
      $('#hidden1').val('calculated value1');
      $('#hidden2').val('calculated value2');
      return false;
    });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9gukqw2f/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. I want to pass the result from result one td. To the hidden input value on the same line. So when I save I can post it to php script. so if result 1 = input first plus input second. I want the result one to go into the hidden 1 value so I can post it.

Comment: @creaven `calculated value1` and `calculated value2` are just for illustration purposes. You can set the values as required

Comment: how can I make calculated value1 show the innerHTML of the result 1 td. Im sorry 4 - 5 am here my brain is frazzeled.I thinks what is throwing me off is I thinking I should not be able to see the hidden inputs until I post them in to my database?

Comment: Im simply using the hidden input as a way of passing the result one into the database. My Javascript up to this point is fine to get the required results etc its just the problem with not being able to post data from td tags - im guessing using hidden inputs is the solution

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I think I'm going to give up on this and follow @ghosts advice and handle the sums again using php and leave in the javascript for use ability only. At least I will know how to this!